# check array values and change input isCheck (function)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I store true checkbox values in an array,

then after getting the array I want to chanage the checkbox isChecked to true if the checkbox value was in the array,

here is the function :

```
put(array, checkbox){
    for(let ent of checkbox) {    
      for(let entery of array)  {
        ent.val === entery 
        ? ent.isChecked= true
        : ent.isChecked= false
      }
    }
  }
```

here how did I store checkbox :

```
  public home_category = [
    { val: 'غرفة  نوم', isChecked: false },
    { val: 'صالة', isChecked: false },
    { val: 'حوش', isChecked: false },
    { val: 'مجلس', isChecked: false },
    { val: 'غرفة سائق', isChecked: false },
    { val: 'مطبخ', isChecked: false },
    { val: 'ملحق خارجي', isChecked: false },
    { val: 'صالة طعام', isChecked: false },
    { val: 'مستودع', isChecked: false }
  ];
```

this function did not work :(

html :

```
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let entry of home_category">
            <ion-label>{{entry.val}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox slot="end" [(ngModel)]="entry.isChecked"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

Comment: What does the array look like?

Comment: share your html code too

Comment: ["ملحق خارجي","صالة طعام"] this is the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
put(array, checkbox) {
    checkbox.forEach(chk => chk.isChecked = array.includes(chk.val));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `break` to quit `for` loop if find any match.

```
put(array, checkbox){
    for(let ent of checkbox) {    
      for(let entry of array)  {
        if(ent.val === entry){
          ent.isChecked = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```